# Limits of integration change of variables

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the integral $\int^{1}_{-1}f(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ and i want to change the variable to $x=1-2t^2$, then for the limits of integration i get $t=0$ and $t=\pm 1$. Then I have the following

\begin{equation}
\int^{0}_{\pm 1}f(1-2t^2) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}(-2)dt
\end{equation}

How do I proceed? In particular, which limit of integration should I take $+1$ or $-1$?

Comment: If you start with $t=\sqrt {\frac {1-x}2}$ there will be no confusion.

Comment: whenever I perform substitution in integrals, I always do it on indefinite integrals. Then, once I get the answer, I plug in the original variable and then solve for the definite integral. This method avoids confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Substitution with functions (like parabolas) with non-unique (multiply branched) inverse functions should be done by selecting a branch where
the inverse is unique and by sticking with it:
$$x=1-2t^2;$$
$$t= _+\sqrt{(1-x)/2};$$
$$dx=-4t dt;$$
$$
\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
=
-4\int_1^0 t f(1-2x^2)\frac{dt}{\sqrt{-4t^2(t^2-1)}}
$$
$$
=
4\int_0^1 t f(1-2x^2)\frac{dt}{\sqrt{4t^2(1-t^2)}}
=
2\int_0^1 f(1-2x^2)\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$